# Find the area of the parametrized surface $r(u,v)=(u\cos v, \ u\sin v, \ v^2/2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the area of the parametrized surface  $r(u,v)=(u\cos v, \ u\sin v, \ v^2/2)$ for $(u,v)$ such that $u^2+v^2\leq 9$

**Attempt:** should I compute $$\iint_S 1 \,dS \text{ ?} $$ for example changing variables $0\leq r\leq 3$ and $u=r\cos \theta$, $v=r\sin \theta$ $\ \ \ \ $  for $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ is that a good way?

Comment: The area of a parametrized surface is $\int_{A}\left\|\frac{\partial r}{\partial u}\times \frac{\partial r}{\partial v}\right\|\, du\,dv$, where $A$ is the space where the parameters $u,v$ lie.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ok so I take the norm of the cross product of partials. For the limits of the space they should be $\int_0^3 \int_0^{\sqrt{9-v^2}}\|\partial u\times \partial v\| dudv$ right?

Comment: no that only takes care of a quarter of the disk. Anyway, polar coordinates are a good idea (but use a different letter from $r$ for the radial distance, say $0\leq \rho\leq 3$, because you're already using $r$ for the mapping $(u,v)\mapsto r(u,v)$).